# Python's requests producing incomplete reads in docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-requests

I'm trying to download a zip file from FEMA using `python3` and `requests`. The url works when I paste it in the browser and also when I `wget`. There's a redirect and I see it being successfully redirected using `requests`. However, the returned content has significantly fewer bytes than what I expected, like a malformed zip.

Here's the URL and snippet of code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/NFHL/Download/ProductsDownLoadServlet?DFIRMID=10001C&state=DELAWARE&county=KENT COUNTY&fileName=10001C_20190130.zip'
>>> resp = requests.get(url)
>>> len(resp.content)
2583
>>> resp.headers['content-length']
'66892906'
>>> resp.url
'https://hazards.fema.gov/nfhlv2/output/County/10001C_20190130.zip'
```

**UPDATE**: I was running this in a docker container. Outside of the container, it's working as expected.

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, May 10 2019, 15:15:13)
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.21.0'
>>> url = 'https://hazards.fema.gov/nfhlv2/output/County/10001C_20190130.zip'
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> len(r.content)
66892906
>>>
```

Comment: *Is* it a malformed zip file? Did you compare the content with the expected result? Is it possible that the other techniques you used (browser, wget) automatically unzipped the response, but Python did not?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure about the malformed file. I wrote it to a `.zip` and tried to unzip but I got a warning that it's a bad zip. The content I received in bytes is [here](https://gist.github.com/koshy1123/e97b59e03e6dd694b83987a78c2c7540). The browser and wget methods download a `.zip` file, so I don't think it unzips the response.